# High performance CUDA uniform float random number generator within device function

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, cuda, gpu

I need a random number generator with high performance that is used for Monte Carlo calculation on particle transport. The requirements are:

1. Independently generated by each thread
2. The period of the generator should be larger than 2^40

I have tried Tausworthe generator(mathematics of computation, 65, 213 (1996), 203-213), whose period is 2^88. The device function is as follows:

```
__device__ float GenerateRNF(unsigned int *seed, int seedNum=3)
{
    unsigned int s1 = seed[0];
    unsigned int s2 = seed[1];
    unsigned int s3 = seed[2];
    unsigned int b = (((s1 << 13)^s1) >> 19);
    s1 = (((s1 & 0xFFFFFFFE) << 12)^b);
    b = (((s2 << 2) ^ s2) >> 25);
    s2 = (((s2 & 0xFFFFFFF8) << 4) ^ b);
    b = (((s2 << 3) ^ s3) >> 11);
    s3 = (((s3 & 0xFFFFFFF0) << 17) ^ b);
    return ((s1 ^ s2 ^ s3) * 2.32830644e-10f);
}
```

The parameter from seed should be register numbers, and this function is invoked hundreds of times by one thread. 
Each thread matains it’s own seed sequence. If the block size is 64, the thread number is 1024, then the initial seed number initialized in host would be 1024*64*3.

However, the above generator is still very slow. I have tried park-miller algorithm, the speed is several times boost compared to Tausworthe generator (using CUDA double multiply operation tested in GTX1070)

However, it’s periods is much smaller than 2^40.

My question is, is there any random number generator, whose period is better than park-miller algorithm, but it’s speed is several times better than Tausworthe generator? The function form is limited to the above sample. Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you looked at [cuRAND](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html)?

Comment: You are encountering a basic trade-off between quality and speed. You could try George Marsaglia's KISS generator ([bug-fixed version here](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007)), but it likely has performance very similar to your current Tausworthe PRNG.

Comment: 1. Can cuRAND device function be wrapped as the function format I required? 2. If yes, which generator could be faster theoretically? Honestly, I do not see the reason why it should be much faster.

Comment: Maybe you want to try mrg32k3a. It's state vector is small, and should perform comparably. It is implemented in curand. Xorwow should also play well.

Comment: Are you sure that the PRNG is the bottleneck? If it is very important to speed up can you use hardware solution for random number generation?

Comment: You could create a 64-bit [Linear feedback shift register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register). That'll give you a period of 2^64-1. The results aren't exactly uniform, but they might be good enough for your purposes. The's also the [Xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift). That article includes an example of one that has a period of 2^128-1.

Comment: @TodorBalabanov I replaced the random generator, it showed great speed improvement but the randomless is not good enough for park-miller method. What is the suggested hardware that can output to gpu with high bandwidth?

Comment: @tera I have tried to replace my function GenerateRNF by curand_norm, but the performance of the whole process is several times bad.

Comment: @JannusYU I think you may again compare different levels of quality when comparing your generator to CURAND. CURAND gives you *uncorrelated* streams of random numbers for each thread; in your current code I don't see the work needed to generate uncorrelated streams, so likely they are correlated. Proper parallelization has startup overhead (e.g. for PRNG skip-ahead), which disproportionally affects short streams. **How many random numbers in total are you generating per thread, and how many threads are you running?** If you need low startup overhead, try the Philox generator in CURAND.

Comment: @JannusYU `curand_normal()` returns random numbers with *normal* distribution, and is therefore slower than `curand_uniform()` which returns random numbers with uniform distribution. Your current code generates a uniform distribution, so presumably you want `curand_uniform()`.